# OpenCV - Image not being displayed after numpy copy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to read the ".jpg" images in python using cv2.imread() into a numpy array. The code seems fine to me but when I display images using plt.imshow() I see the image not being displayed correctly after I copy the image into the array. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Get current working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

# Read the csv file into a data frame
driving_log_df = pd.read_csv('driving_log.csv')
print(driving_log_df.shape)

X_data_set = np.empty([len(driving_log_df['Center'])*3, 32, 32, 3])
Y_data_set = np.empty(len(driving_log_df['Center'])*3)
print(X_data_set.shape)
print(Y_data_set.shape)

# Path to images 
images_path = cwd + "/IMG"
print(images_path)

# Index 
index = 0

for file in os.listdir(images_path):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(images_path, file), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)        
    image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32))

    # OpenCV reads images in the BGR format, convert them into RGB
    image_rgb =  cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Copy the image 
    X_data_set[index] = np.copy(image_rgb)

    # Display images
    if(index==0):
        figure1 = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(image_rgb)        
        figure2 = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(X_data_set[0])

    index = index + 1
```

Also attached are the images being displayed.

[image: Image being Copied]
[image: Image after Copy]

Answer (score 0):

The axis order in cv2 is bgr. So you need to np.transpose to rgb.

Comment: I am using this statement cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) to convert the image from BGR to RGB.

Comment: Sorry did not see that. I don't use CV2 but have had similar problems with the RGB/BGR thing. I should check the inputs to this are 32bit (each pixel not 32*32). Or try with other packages like pillow unless you really need CV2 - I tried it once and gave up for exactly these kinds of issues!